# Trigger to insert data into table on a specific day every month

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-trigger

I need to write a trigger to insert data into one table from another table on 2nd day of every month in SQL Server. Can anyone help me with a trigger query that will insert data for the above scenario?

Comment: What do you expect as an answer here? You have not provided any kind of detail about what you want. Here is a good place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: A trigger reacts to a DML events (update, insert, delete), if you want to do something on 2nd of every month you need to schedule a job.

Comment: Why do u need `trigger ` to insert data on a specific day of every month  ?

Comment: @HoneyBadger Thanks for the tip. I will try to schedule a job with the SQL query to insert data into a table

Comment: to insert date on a specified date of month  you can use this as an example `if DAY(getdate()) = '02'
begin  
insert into foo (x)
select 'myname' 
end`

Comment: Maybe you just need a job? Whith schedule "every 2nd of the month"?

Comment: It's worth noting that, in SQL Server, a database trigger (which you've tagged) is something that is created (unsurprisingly) at database level, not table/view/etc level. These normally occur on DDL changes (such as a table being altered or, perhaps, one being dropped or created) rather that DML changes.

Comment: @BHouse I just thought If I write a trigger, it will insert data automatically to the table every month. Guess I should have been looking to schedule a job rather than a trigger

Comment: @sow I guess u have read comment from @larnu, You can not use `Trigger` for that timely operation. I would suggest create a SP, or merge script and schedule it everyday if u like using my above indicated script or schedule it on the specific day. It might be worth of adding inserted date column  as default `getdate()` to your source data table to see changes. For more info, pelase check https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/2911/working-with-triggers/